# Combine two ActiveRecord Query results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have two active record queries that I would like to combine together

```
joins("join relationships ON user_id = followed_id").
              where("follower_id = #{user.id}")
```

and

```
where(:user_id => user.id)
```

Basically I want the results of the second one to appear with the first similar to a `UNION` statement in SQL. Can it be done in ActiveRecord in this way?

I would prefer to use a union rather that have to join all the `followed_id`s in a string and use the `IN` clause in sql.

Any ideas?

-----Edit------
I am looking for a way to get this to work with lazy loading

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `relation & relation`:

```
Model.joins("join relationships ON user_id = followed_id").where("follower_id = {user.id}") & Model.where(:user_id => user.id)
```

Comment: This forces ActiveRecord to put the results in an array eagerly. Can this be done with lazy loading?

Comment: btw.. I did vote up your answer since it got me there part of the way.

Comment: Shouldn't that be relation | relation? ActiveRecord::Relation quacks like an array and [1]&[2]==[] but [1]|[2]=[1,2].

Comment: The `&` method on ActiveRecord::Relation is a alias for `merge`, and this alias has been removed as of Rails 3.0.9. It was removed for exactly the confusion that @MikeJohnson points out: it's not the appropriate operator. Use `relation.merge(other_relation)` instead.

Comment: @zzawaideh just wondering if you have any idea how you solved this problem I am trying to retrieve two tables but need it as ActiveRecord::Relation not an array. any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Wow, so "merge" puts them together with an AND. What would be the OR equivalent?

Comment: @Arcolye Did you ever figure out the OR equivalent to the relation.merge?

Comment: @Neil Watch this issue in the rails repo:
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9052

Answer (score 32):

This was useful for me:

```
Model.where(...) | Model.where(...)
```

Comment: This converts the ActiveRecord_Relation to Array object. You can't apply active record methods like .where etc. on the resulting objects

Comment: Thanks! can you explain how this work? "|" operator in ruby

Answer (score 1):

This was useful for me:

An updated version of Rails/ActiveRecord may support this syntax natively. It would look similar to:

```
Model.where(foo: 'bar').or.where(bar: 'bar')
```

Or you can, simply sticking with the following works great:

```
Model.where('foo= ? OR bar= ?', 'bar', 'bar')
```

referred to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639656/activerecord-or-query)