# ActiveRecord: "Or" command?

Tags: activerecord

When writing activerecord queries, I typically just use regular sql syntax [field_a = 'b' OR field_c = 'd'] when I need to use "or" in query. I'm just wondering if there's a way to do it without resorting to sql? Have tried googling 'activerecord or' but, unsurprisingly, not much joy.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible (yet) using ActiveRecord alone. The parts of the relation are always ANDed together, so the only option is to use a SQL string for that part of the .where()

Otherwise you can resort to Arel for now:
[ActiveRecord OR query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639656/activerecord-or-query)

Answer (score 0):

With Ruby on Rails 5 you are able to do the following chaining using `ActiveRecord::Relation#or` method:

```
    Person.where(name: 'Neil').or(Person.where(age: 27))
```

You can check the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or)  and the [examples](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/test/cases/relation).