# How do I re-write "Feedback.where('poster_id = 3 OR receiver_id = 3')" in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is there a way to write it in a more 'Rails-friendly' way?

i.e. if I were searching for anyone of those attributes, I would just do `Feedback.where(:poster_id => 3)` and it would be good.

But how do I achieve the `OR` in the Rails 3 friendly syntax (as opposed to the `SQL` friendly one).

Also, if it is `better` to use my original one over the desired one, why is it better?

Thanks.

**Edit 1**: Btw, if I do `Feedback.where(:poster_id => 3, :receiver_id => 3)` that returns the result for the `AND` operation, which is the exact opposite of what I want. So I feel so close, just not quite there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by putting SQL fragments in the where() arguments. For more information you can [look at the ActiveRecord querying guide.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

```
Feedback.where("poster_id = ? OR receiver_id = ?", 1, 3)
```

You can do this without SQL fragments [as described in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639656/activerecord-or-query):

```
t = Feedback.arel_table
Feedback.where(t[:poster_id].eq(1).or(t[:receiver_id].eq(2)))
```

Comment: That's the same thing as my original statement, imho...if not worse - in terms of extra execution needed at the application level.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question. I thought you were asking how to use an OR condition with ActiveRecord 3. What is your actual question? What extra execution is needed at the application level?

Comment: Well I guess a more specific question would be how can I use an `OR` condition without using SQL fragments?

Comment: Ok...will stick with the SQL then. The other way feels messy :)