# Testing for an empty string in an ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In a Rails app, what is the cleanest way to check if a property is nil or empty using the ActiveRecord `where` method?

This works, but it seems that there should be a nicer, built-in way to do it:

```
@items = Item.where :context => nil || ''
```

It's hard to do much with Google-fu when your search includes terms like "where."

Comment: Your `where` does complicate things a bit, but does [`.blank?()`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) help you at all?

Comment: Where would that go in the code above? `Item.where :context.blank?()` returns an unfiltered list, and `Item.where :context => .blank?()` throws a syntax error.

Comment: `@items = Item.where :context => nil || ''` won't check for null values, because `nil || ''` evaluates to just '', so the resulting query will just be `SELECT * FROM items WHERE context = ''`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

```
Item.where(context: [nil, ''])
```

Answer (score 16):

What you have wouldn't work.

```
@items = Item.where context: nil || ''
```

really evaluates to:

```
@items = Item.where context: ''
```

So you wouldn't find items with `context` set to `nil` using this method.

**Side Note**

Using `thing || other` in this way never works. You cannot write `if item == 'test' || 'something'` and expect it to work in cases where `item` is `'something'`. It would only work in cases where `item` is `'test'`. To get something like this to work you would need to write `if item == 'test' || item == 'something'`. This isn't how humans talk, but it is how computers read.

**Back to the main event**

One way to write a query that would work is:

```
Item.where("context = ? or context = ?", nil, '')
```

This reads as: find all Items where `context` is `nil` or `context` is `''`.

While this works, it's not considered particularly "Rails-y". A better way would be:

```
Item.where(context: [nil, ''])
```

This reads as: find all Items where `context` is in `[nil, '']`.

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639656/activerecord-or-query)

Comment: I wanted to account for both `""` and `''` so I crafted something like `Item.where("context = ? or context = ? or context = ?", nil, '', "")`. Found soon I didn't need both `""` and `''` because they are equal in Ruby's eyes.

Answer (score 0):

I like to avoid this problem by setting a default value for such columns.

If that isn't an option for you then you'll need to use a SQL clause.

```
@items = Item.where "`items`.`context`='' OR `items`.`context` IS NULL"
```

I use the Squeel gem (http://erniemiller.org/projects/squeel/) which makes it easy to use OR operators.  I recommend checking it out.  An example with Squeel would be:

```
@items = Item.where{context.eq('') | context.eq(nil)}
```