# How to use OR condition in ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to grab all the users that either have an email as the one supplied or the first and last name. So for example:

```
users = User.where(:first_name => "James", :last_name => "Scott")
```

which will return all the users that have the first and last name of "James" & "Scott".

```
users = User.where(:email => "james@gmail.com")
```

which will return the user with the email as "james@gmail.com".

Is there a way to do a `where` clause to return either the users with the same first and last name and the user with the email that matches in one `where` query or do I need to do a merge on the 2 separate `where` clauses.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActiveRecord OR query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639656/activerecord-or-query)

Comment: @Trace: you forgot to select an answer or at least give some feedback.

Answer (score 68):

Rails 5 comes with an [`or` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or).

This method accepts an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. eg:

```
User.where(first_name: 'James', last_name: 'Scott')
    .or(User.where(email: 'james@gmail.com'))
```

Comment: For Rails 5 application this should be considered the most correct answer.

Comment: probably it should better be `or(unscoped.where(email: 'james@gmail.com'))`

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
users = User.where("(first_name = 'James' and last_name = 'Scott') or email = 'james@gmail.com'")
```

To interpolate variables:

```
users = User.where("(first_name = ? and last_name = ?) or email = ?", first_name, last_name, email)
```

Answer (score 10):

If you prefer a DSL approach (with no SQL), can use the underlying Arel layer:

```
t = User.arel_table
users = User.where(
  (t[:first_name].eq('Ernie').and(t[:last_name].eq('Scott')).
    or(t[:email].eq('james#gmail.com'))
)
```

That's a bit ugly, but if you use some wrapper over Arel (for example, [this one](https://gist.github.com/1333253)), the code is much nicer:

```
users = User.where(
  ((User[:first_name] == 'Ernie') & (User[:last_name] == 'Scott')) |
   (User[:email] == 'james#gmail.com')
)
```

Comment: Interesting wrapper, I've always disliked having to use arel, but I might be less averse to it with this; nice.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to write SQL as the others have mentioned, you could access the arel structures directly (looks like another answer has that) or use the [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) gem to do it much more elegantly:

```
User.where{(first_name == 'Ernie') & (last_name == 'Scott') | (email == 'james#gmail.com')}
```

Comment: yeah I guess that would be more like ruby.  In any case, it would need a tweak to use variables as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use string conditions, as in `Client.where("orders_count = ? AND locked = ?", params[:orders], false)`, and use `OR` in conjunction with `AND`. Be careful with the priority of those operators though.

Cf [Active Record Query Interface guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions)