# How to build a SQL 'OR' query by using Rails facilities?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and, given I have stated all needed classes/models involved in this question, I would like to build the following SQL query statement (note the SQL `OR`) "a là Ruby on Rails way":

```
SELECT customers.* FROM customers WHERE (firstname = 'James' OR firstname = 'Paula') AND lastname = 'Brown'
```

Is it possible by using Rails facilities?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use OR condition in ActiveRecord query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871131/how-to-use-or-condition-in-activerecord-query)

Comment: @tokland I don't think so. See my answer(and others).

Comment: @Anil: well, I understood the point was how to make a OR, not that the field was the same (then indeed it's ok a `IN (?)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not really looking for an OR. Rather, you are looking for an IN.

```
SELECT customers.* FROM customers WHERE firstname IN ('James','Paula') AND lastname = 'Brown'
```

This has been supported in Rails for a long time(may be since its inception). You can specify an array of values instead of a single value in your finds.

```
@firstnames = ['James','Paula']
@lastname = 'Brown'
@customers = Customer.find_all_by_firstname_and_lastname(@firstnames,@lastname)
```

Comment: Those finders are going to be deprecated in Rails 4. You should instead use `Customer.where(first_name: @firstnames, last_name: @lastname)`

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to do that, if you don't want to use any external gem like [squeel](http://railscasts.com/episodes/354-squeel), is to build a scope for the purpose:

```
scope :by_first_and_last_name, ->(firsts, last) { 
   where(['firstname in (?) AND lastname = ?', firsts, last])
}
```

Since it returns an Arel you can chain it normally with other scopes.

You can use it like this:

```
YourModel.by_first_and_last_name(['Foo','Bar'], 'Baz').first
```

Comment: metawhere is rails 2, you are looking for Ernie's rewrite called squeel https://github.com/ernie/squeel.  On this same topic Ryan Bates makes some interesting points about this in a recent Railscast (pro) http://railscasts.com/episodes/355-hacking-with-arel

Comment: @Fabrizio He is looking for (firstname or firstname) AND lastname.

Comment: @Anil sorry I misread the question. Just to be consistent I'll update my answer, but the IN approach is clearly a better one.

Answer (score 1):

The following code would allow you the same effectiveness as multiple `OR`s on the firstname field:

```
Customer.where(['firstname IN (?) AND lastname = ?', ['James', 'Paula'], 'Brown'])
```