# How to use greater than with "or" condition in Activerecord?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, activerecord

How do I use greater than together with "or" condition in activerecord?
Here is what I am trying to do:

```
@contract_dues_now = ContractDue.where(:status => ['Unpaid', 'Partially Paid']).
  where(due_date: Date.today || ContractDue.arel_table[:due_date].gt(Date.today)).
  group(:contract_id).order(:due_date)
```

It doesnt seems correct to me as I this query result didnt output the OR statement like it suppose to:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871131/how-to-use-or-condition-in-activerecord-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
@contract_dues_now = ContractDue.where(:status => ['Unpaid', 'Partially Paid']).
    where('contract_dues.due_date = ? OR contract_dues.due_date > ?', Date.today, Date.today).
    group(:contract_id).order(:due_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

arel supports or operator.

`where(ContractDue.arel_table[:due_date].eq(Date.today).or(ContractDue.arel_table[:due_date].gt(Date.today)))`

https://github.com/rails/arel#more-sophisticated-queries