# where condition in rails3 with OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user table in that department_id is one of the field and i have to check two condition where :department_id=>current_user.id or department_id=> null.

I do not know how to write query for this in rails3.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the documentation or tried to write anything yet?

Comment: Everything you need can be found here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639656/activerecord-or-query

Comment: Thanks! yes i solved it and your answer is correct but i donot have  that much points i can give u points or tick your answer :P

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example assuming you have a Customer model.

```
Customer.where("department_id = ? OR department_id IS NULL", current_user.id)
```

You may also check the guides here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions