# Transformation of query to active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

To perform a range query we follow something akin to the syntax below -:

```
oms[:order_items].where(:internal_sla => 3..5) results in this query
 => #<Sequel::Mysql2::Dataset: "SELECT * FROM `order_items` WHERE ((`internal_sla` >= 3) AND (`internal_sla` <= 5))">
```

But how can I change the active record query to give me something like this => `select internal_sla from order_items where (internal_sla<=3 and internal_sla>=0) OR (internal_sla<=15 and internal_sla>=10)`

Answer (score 1):

```
.where("(internal_sla >= ? AND internal_sla <= ? OR 
internal_sla >= ? AND internal_sla <= ? )", 0, 3, 10, 15).pluck(:internal_sla)
```

**UPDATE** after comment:

If internal_sla is integer, you can:

```
.where(:internal_sla => (0..3).to_a + (10..15).to_a).pluck(:internal_sla)
```

**edit:** fixed typo

Comment: I specifically want it in active record conditions....My query is more than a dozen lines for advanced search, so don't want to hardcode anything. So I usually pass something like this conditions[:order_items][:status]=params[:order_item_status] if params[:order_item_status].present? So the conditions keep getting added up. Btw above query acts like in 'order_items'.'status' in ('approved','shipped')

Comment: A little edit to your thing, and voila it worked :-) oms_b2c[:order_items].where(:internal_sla => (0..3).to_a + (10..15).to_a) .

Comment: oops, there was a typo indeed.

Comment: The point of this answer is: you can't really do it in ActiveRecord, you have to just stick your SQL right in.  You might want to try the squeel gem: https://github.com/ernie/squeel

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
oms[:order_items].where(:internal_sla => [0..3, 10..15])
```

Comment: Error: can't express 0..3 as a SQL literal....Doesn't work, one of the first things I tried. :(

Comment: My Bad luck! I checked it in mysql and it worked, so answered :-(

Comment: by the way, Which database you are using?