# Rails: Where Date.today is past OR is the :deadline_date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Basically, I'm a little stuck here. I'm using Rails 3.x.x.. The code I'm using now is as follows

```
@email_reminder = ToDo.where(:reminder => true, :deadline_date =< Date.today)
```

The code above obviously won't work. I googled around but almost every solution was a Rails 2.x.x. solution. **What's the most efficient way of finding all my "email_reminders" if today's date is past OR is the deadline_date?**

(doesn't have to be similar to method used above but it would help if you provide a way using a similar method)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a native `OR` operation in `ActiveRecord`.  What example have you found?

Comment: Possible solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5000839/2525797 (would need to be tweaked, obviously).

Comment: @EricPalace One of the answers is "Model.where(:column => ["value", "other_value"]" -- how would I do this when using a "less than OR equal to" condition?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

To do `OR` statements with Rails, I always use [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel).

Should be something like

```
@email_reminder = ToDo.where{ (:reminder => true) | (:deadline_date =< Date.today) }
```

**EDIT:**

I've never seen the comma used to separate the two parts of the query (not sure that's possible), I would do it like this (2 `where` clauses are joined by `AND` in `ActiveRecord`:

```
 @email_reminder = ToDo.where(:reminder => true).where({ deadline_date <= Date.today })
```

Without `squeel` it would be something like

```
.where("deadline_date <= ?", Date.today)
```

Also, notice I flipped the `=` and `<` sign in the query

Comment: I would like for the "reminder =>" part to be constant. I want the "Or" statement for the date only (today's date 'is' OR 'past' the deadline_date)

Comment: Typo in your code? `<=` instead of `=<`?.  Also, updating code to reflect changes

Comment: I'm searching for all the "ToDos" that have a reminder boolean set to true and the deadline date is past Or is today's date.

Comment: Sorry, still need `squeel`. Updating

Comment: So I think it was just a matter of separating the query into 2 `where` clauses and then getting the right syntax of `<=`? I'm pretty sure the `<=` means today's date OR before

Comment: I might just stick to the "column ?" way of doing things like this. Adding 2 seperate 'where' conditions seems unnecessary & I thought there was a simpler way like the code in my original question. Thanks anyway & I'll checkout "squeel."

Answer (score 9):

I see no reason to install a gem to fix this one issue. If you use some good 'ol SQL :)

`@email_reminder = ToDo.where(:reminder => true).where('deadline_date <= ?', Date.today)`

*Note the order of the less than or equal to.*

Granted if you run into issues like this a lot, Squeel might be worth looking into. However, I tend to stray away from libraries that use the word 'hackery'