# Rails ActiveRecord where or clause

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, where-clause

I'm looking to write an ActiveRecord query and this is what I have below.  Unfortunately you can't use OR like this.  What's the best way to execute?  `category_ids` is an array of integers.

```
.where(:"categories.id" => category_ids).or.where(:"category_relationships.category_id" => category_ids)
```

Comment: It's also improper use of the `hash` symbol, `:`

Comment: which table are your trying to retrieve, Category or something else associated with it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActiveRecord OR query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639656/activerecord-or-query)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way is to revert to raw sql...

```
YourModel.where("categories.id IN ? OR category_relationships.category_id IN ?", category_ids, category_ids)
```

Comment: To avoid having to say `category_ids` twice you can use this syntax: `.where("categories.id IN :c OR category_relationships.category_id IN :c", c: category_ids)`

Answer (score 7):

Keep the SQL out of it and use ARel, like this:

```
.where(Category.arel_table[:id].in(category_ids).
  or(CategoryRelationship.arel_table[:category_id].in(category_ids))
```

Comment: While it's fun and neat to abstract out SQL, it's hard to see any gains by doing so. I would argue it's much harder to read. If you're bothering to compile your Ruby when you build, you could catch errors then, but your RSpec tests will also catch those errors. You did write tests, right?

Comment: ARel is the perfect anti pattern example for people who want to apply the KISS principle.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to return Categories, you need to OUTER JOIN category_relationships and put a OR condition on the combined table.

```
Category.includes(:category_relationships).where("categories.id IN (?) OR category_relationships.category_id IN (?)",category_ids,category_ids )
```

This query is creating an outer join table by combining columns of `categories` and `category_relationships`. Unlike an inner join (e.g. `Category.joins(:category_relationships)`), outer join table would also have `categories` with no associated `category_relationship`. It would then apply the conditions in `where`clause on the outer join table to return the matching records.

`includes` statement without conditions on the association usually makes two separate sql queries to retrieve the records and their association. However when used with conditions on the associated table, it would make a single query to create an outer join table and run conditions on the outer join table. This allows you to retrieve records with no association as well.

See [this](http://www.spacevatican.org/2008/4/29/include-and-conditions/) for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score -3):

What you want to do is manually write the OR part of the query like this:

`.where("category.id in (#{category_ids.join(',')}) OR category_relationships.category_id in (#{category_ids.join(',')})")`

Comment: Some security advice: unless you can fully trust all of your query parameters, it's best to use the escaped query syntax, e.g. `where("categories.id IN (?) OR category_relationships.category_id IN (?)", category_ids, category_ids)`.