# How to use or in rails hash query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been using the following syntax when querying in my rails project.

```
Table.where({ fld_1: "val_1", fld_2: "val_2" })
```

which will generate the following sql

```
SELECT * FROM tables WHERE fld_1 = 'val_1' AND fld_2 = 'val_2'
```

However, I want to make a query using **or** not **and** as conditional opoerator.
**Ex** `SELECT * FROM tables WHERE fld_1 = 'val_1' or fld_2 = 'val_2'`

I can attain it using this query

```
Table.where(["fld_1 = ? and fld_2 = ?", "val_1", "val_2"])
```

But how can I achieve it using the Hash style of querying.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Rails documentation on Hash querying](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions):

> Only equality, range and subset checking are possible with Hash conditions.

So your best bet would be to skip the hash and use an Array like you mentioned:

```
Table.where('fld_1= ? OR fld_2= ?', 'val_1', 'val_2')
```

---

Fortunately, `or` conditions similar to what you're looking for [will be coming in Rails 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27544935/3448554) ([which has been backported to Rails 4.2.2](https://gist.github.com/bf4/84cff9cc6ac8489d769e)).  When it comes out you will be able write your query like this:

```
Table.where(fld_1: 'val_1').or.where(fld_2: 'val_2')
```