# Find a records containg a specific tag

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a following DB schema:

```
User
- id
- name (String)

UserTag
- user_id
- tag_id

Tag
- id
- key (String)
```

And i also have a pretty complex users-search chain with a lot of `where` statements. I'm trying to figure out how to include one another where condition to my chain - filtering for users that has a specific tag assigned (ID of this tag is unknown, just it's `key` is known).

So, here is more or less how my code looks:

```
col = User.all

col = col.where('cats_count <= 0') if args[:no_cat]
col = col.where('dogs_count <= 0') if args[:no_dog]
col = col.where('other_pets_count <= 0') if args[:no_other_pet]

# ... tag logic filtering here ...

col = col.where('age > 100') if args[:old]
```

And i want to filter for a users, who has a `Tag` with `key=non_smoking` assigned. Ideally, i would love it to be database-engine independen, if that's important - i'm on sqlite/postgres.

Honestly i have completely no any ideas on how to deal with that, i probably lack some knowledge in SQL matter and then, in Rails/ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify `joins` and the put [conditions on the joined tables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables). So maybe something like (untested, off the top of my head)

```
col.joins(user_tags: :tag).where(user_tags: { tag: { key: 'non_smoking' } })
```

Comment: BTW, don't you need something between each `col.where`  ? like a `OR` / `AND` ? it bother the SQL-me...

Comment: By default chained `where` s use 'AND', but you can get it to be 'OR' if you need it (see [ActiveRecord OR query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639656/activerecord-or-query))