# Ruby Activerecord: find same value in multiple fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I use the following query in SQL to find the same value in multiple fields of my model but would like to do it in a more correct Activerecord way.

```
MyModel.where("'some_value' in (a_field, another_field)").first.try(:id)
```

The following does not work since it's an AND and I need an OR

```
MyModel.where(a_field: 'some_value', another_field: 'some_value').first.try(:id)
```

Any suggestions ?
Out of curiosity: if I use the first (which works) and use a `puts` or `p` to view the result I see the results two times ? I wonder why..

EDIT in this example I use only two fields but in reality there could be more so an or wouldn't be doable and not dry

Comment: _"I need an OR"_ – here it is: [`or`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or)

Comment: possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639656/activerecord-or-query

Comment: @lacostenycoder the question is not for an or but for the better activerecord way, if ther would be multiple fields an or is no good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an `or` method available...

```
MyModel.where(a_field: 'some_value').or(MyModel.where(another_field: 'some_value')).first.try(:id)
```

for multiple fields you could do

```
test_value = 'some_value'

my_models = MyModel.where(id: nil)

%i(a_field another_field third_field fourth_field fifth_field).each do |field|
  my_models = my_models.or(MyModel.where(field => test_value))
end
```

Comment: thx Steve,in my example that could be used, but in reality there are multiple fields and it isn't DRY , if no better suggestion I'll accept and will have to live with the SQL solution iaa

Comment: I've edited to suggest a way you could do it for multiple fields.   I'm not in a position to test this chaining but it should work?

Comment: Sometimes SQL is the best way to go, though. :)

Answer (score 2):

[Ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) is a gem which is used to build complex queries.

It supports both `or` and `and` operators.

For searching on multiple columns with same value you can build ransack query in following way.

`MyModel.ransack(field1_or_field2_or_field3_eq: 'some_value')`

Ransack provide various options to get your result like (equal_to condition, like_condition etc...).

If you don't want to use any external gem then I think @steve's answers is apt.

Answer (score 2):

Myltiple ways to do so:

**Rails:**

```
Post.where('id = 1').or(Post.where('id = 2'))
```

refs: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9e42cf019f2417473e7dcbfcb885709fa2709f89

**Use rais_or Gem:**  https://github.com/khiav223577/rails_or

```
EX: user = User.where(account: account).or(email: account).take
```

**Use ARel** # Arel is best for complex queries

```
t = Post.arel_table
results = Post.where(
  t[:author].eq("Someone").
  or(t[:title].matches("%something%"))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot about this question, here is how I do this now

```
def search_in_all_fields model, text
  model.where(
    model.column_names
      .map {|field| "#{field} like '%#{text}%'" }
      .join(" or ")
  )
end
```

Or better as a scope in the model itself

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :search_in_all_fields, ->(text){
    where(
      column_names
        .map {|field| "#{field} like '%#{text}%'" }
        .join(" or ")
    )
  }
end
```

You would just need to call it like this

```
Model.search_in_all_fields "test"
```

Before you start.., to be sure there is no sql injection here still better and shorter

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :search_all_fields, ->(text){
    where("#{column_names.join(' || ')} like ?", "%#{text}%")
  }
end
```