# Active record OR query, querying 2 different column's values present in 2 different lists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

as the title suggests I am trying to query my model. I am trying to query it based of two conditions.
I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639656/activerecord-or-query), though similar it doesn't quite answer my question.

I have tried the following method but it only works if the lists are populated.

```
school.classes.where.not('"classes"."highest_achiever_id" NOT IN (?) OR "classes"."room_id"' NOT IN (?), [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4])
```

The above query is what I am using to retrieve all classes that meet my conditions, my only problem is the case where the list being passed is empty this query seems to return empty results.

Comment: In your question you are doing `WHERE NOT (column_name NOT IN (1,2,3))`. Is that intentional? Because that could just be a regular `WHERE column_name IN (1,2,3)`.

Comment: No wonder I was having issues with my query it should have been `WHERE (column_name NOT IN (1,2,3) )` The 2 NOTs were negating each other.

Comment: i think you could apply the De Morgan's law: `!(A OR B) = !A AND !B`